# Mocked class never always gives Null Pointer when running tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class that extends the CSRF repository of the Spring and where I have written a custom implementation. It looks somewhat like this:

```
public class CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepository implements CsrfTokenRepository {

    @Autowired
    JWKRepository jWKRepository;

    JWK jWK;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        jWK = jWKRepository.findGlobalJWK(null); // This is custom code, there will always be a valid object returned here
    }

    @Override
    public void saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String tokenValue = token == null ? "" : token.getToken();
        log.info("JWK: " + jWK.getPrivateKey());
        // other logics
    }

}
```

And in my tests, I do something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepositoryTest.class, CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepositoryTest.TestConfig.class })
public class CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepositoryTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepository customCookieCsrfTokenRepository() {
            return new CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepository customCookieCsrfTokenRepository;

    @MockBean
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @MockBean
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @MockBean
    RSAUtil rsaUtil;

    @MockBean
    JWKRepository jWKRepository;

    @MockBean
    JWK jWK;

    @Test
    public void saveToken() {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = customCookieCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(request);
        String privateKey = "some key value";
        when(jWK.getPrivateKey()).thenReturn(privateKey);
        customCookieCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken(csrfToken, request, response);
        // some asserts
    }

}
```

So basically, the same token test case actually gets broken saying there is a NullPointer when I try to do `jWK.getPrivateKey()`. I tried to check if `jWK` is the null object but it isn't. I have verified by changing the log to print `jWK` object and it didn't throw any error. However, I am trying to mock and return the `jWK` object in my test case. Why doesn't this work? What's wrong with the above code? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things here:

**1)** The JWK field is not an `@Autowired` field, thus `@MockBean` will not work on it. We need to use a simple `@Mock` on that field in the test.

**2)** In the `@PostConstruct` it is assigned based on the result of the `jWKRepository.findGlobalJWK(null)`.

**3)** We need to mock that method:

```
@Before
private void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}    

@Mock
JWK jWK;

@Test
public void saveToken() {
    when(jWKRepository.findGlobalJWK(null)).thenReturn(jWK);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, yes your right with the approach. I didn't know about those mistakes. However, it doesn't solve the problem and I still keep getting NullPointer at the same place.

Comment: Is jWK object null? Or is it a mocked one?

Comment: Not sure if its a mocked one but it is not null. I changed log statement from `log.info("JWK: " + jWK.getPrivateKey());` to `log.info("JWK: " + jWK);` and it went through that line without issues. Another thing I tried is returning the mock jwk inside the init itself and that also didn't work.

Comment: Add full stack trace in the post

Comment: I didn't do a clean build. On a clean build things work great.